# Shell script syntax error in expression

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I'm trying to make self extracting file using the following Ant tasks:

```
...
<fixcrlf file="${src.dir}/scripts/install.sh" eol="unix"/>

<concat destfile="${build.dir}/my_program.exe" binary="yes">
    <fileset file="${src.dir}/scripts/install.sh" />
    <fileset file="${build.dir}/program.tar.gz" />
</concat>
```

.. and my_program.exe looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

begin=`head -30 $0 | grep -n ^START | cut -d ':' -f -1`   # find line number of the marker 
start=$(($begin+1))   # beginning of the binary archive which will be extracted                 

echo $start

...

START
#binary file starts
```

When I run my_program.exe I get the following error:

```
./my_program.exe: line 4: Binary file (standard input) matches: syntax error in expression (error token is "file (standard input) matches")
tail: +: invalid number of lines
```

When I run install.sh separately it finds line number just fine.

My guess is that something wrong with Ant task. Do I miss some properties that will fix it?

Comment: Is there an easy way to test my_program.exe (which is really a bash script) separately? Does it work outside of ant? I would be surprised if it did. Good Luck

Comment: I just want a number line, when you script returns <line number>:String
Also, like I wrote when I run install.sh separately it finds line number fine.

Comment: Sorry, your mention of my_program.exe threw me off. The answer from bmk looks to be a good solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should use the `-a` (resp. `--text`, meaning to *process a binary file as if it were text*) option of `grep`. Otherwise `grep` will only output `"Binary file matches"`.

So probably the line 4 should be:

```
begin=`head -30 $0 | grep -na ^START | cut -d ':' -f -1`   # find line number of the marker
```